# What are all the differences between Ark: Survival Evolved and its mobile variant?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I've recently started playing *Ark: Survival Evolved* on PS4 only to find out that there's a mobile version as well afterwards. I've noticed some differences, from engrams available to resources you can collect.

I couldn't find a complete list of all the differences. So far I could only locate [this list in the official wiki](https://ark.gamepedia.com/ARK:_Survival_Evolved_Mobile#Differences_from_standard_ARK), but I've also noticed that there are clams on the small south-east island on *The Island* on mobile, while there aren't any on the standard variant for instance. So it looks to me like the list isn't exhaustive.

What are **all** the differences between **Ark: Survival Evolved** and **Ark: Survival Evolved - Mobile 2.0**?

Comment: Maybe the answer can be created as a community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Ark has a lot of differences with the PC and Mobile version. The mobile version forces you to purchase 'god mode' and with the console and PC version you do not have to do that.

On PC you have much different maps like Genisis and Scorched Earth, mobile you can't even pay for that.

On mobile things are a bit easier, but that kind of spoils the fun.

On PC you can join servers and play with many different people, on mobile you can do that but the servers are restricted to verified servers.

There are many more differences though.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t know all of them but I do know some: more bosses, more worlds, trek creatures, more obelisks. There are a lot of things. Why is it different? Because the company that made ARK mobile made it so it would have less stuff.